# typeahead.js: how to open the menu on click

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I am trying to open the suggestions menu on `click` event. according to the documentation [this method](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#jquerytypeaheadopen) should open the menu, but it didn't work for me.

html:

```
<div class="inner-addon right-addon">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
    <input type="text" id="customer_name" name="Operation[customer_id]" class="form-control" placeholder="Mention Customer Name"/>
</div>
```

js:

```
 var countries = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: '<?= Yii::getAlias('@web').'/js/countries.json'; ?>'
});

$('#customer_name').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'countries',
    source: countries
});

$('.operation-create .glyphicon-search').click(function(){
    $('#customer_name').typeahead('open');
});
```

when click the glyphicon, a 'tt-open' class added to the menu element, but its display remains none and the data not loaded.

Comment: dont you need `class="typeahead"` as a class?  
https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: @morne it functions the same, with & without class